# Are questions about how to arrange office space for optimal co-worker interactions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

The question [What is the best way to arrange three desks so we don't kick each other?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/what-is-the-best-way-to-arrange-three-desks-so-we-dont-kick-each-other) was recommended for migration to the Workplace.

Should questions about how to arrange office space or desks for optimal employee communication, effectiveness, or minimal tension be on-topic here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds just fine to me. The focus is on a workplace issue and it's quite definitely answerable; in fact it already has good answers from users of an absolutely fabulous site! Normally I wouldn't migrate old questions, but this one isn't *that* old and is not a poor question (in my opinion).

We've already pretty much agreed that furniture related questions are okay as long as they relate to Workplace related issues in [Are questions about office furniture off topic?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/are-questions-about-office-furniture-off-topic) and I don't think this situation is much different. We also have an [office-layout](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-layout) tag where this would fit just fine.

I've migrated the question.

Comment: Nice. I was actually going to ask a question along these lines yesterday (more related to general facilities management, but related to the question in question).