# Asking about a specific type of office supply

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Wanted to check about this question in meta before I go posting it anywhere:

I am looking for a very particular type of clipboard, specifically an 8 1/2 x 11 version of [this](http://www.cgetools.com/double-clip-clipboard) (the one depicted can only be purchased in 6x9). It is for my office as we often work outside in windy conditions.

[image: Double clip clipboard]

I've spent a fair amount of time googling but cannot find what I am looking for. There are many strange "weatherproof" designs, but I need something simple.

I believe that I am using incorrect search terms or that I don't know what industry this item would most commonly be used in. Is there a way for me to phrase a question so that it would be on topic? Perhaps asking, "What is the technical name for this item?" or "What industry would I find a double clip clipboard in?" (if that is even the correct name for this item).

If there is not a way to phrase the question so that it is on topic could someone suggest a decent forum I might be able to go to and ask? Also I am not sure if there is a better location on stack for this question than "workplace".

**Note:** I believe that [this question about office furniture](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/are-questions-about-office-furniture-off-topic) is similar, but it asked more about how to deal with the culture in the office rather than particular information about furniture itself.

Answer (score 5):

I keep overthinking this. It is a straightforward question that will help you solve a practical answerable problem involving the workplace. That should be on topic here by my best estimation. If the community disagrees, we can discuss it again if it gets closed without an answer, but for now I'd say just go with it. Solve that problem.